# Azure API management choose policy for restricting particular group

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am trying to restrict a group from accessing an operation. but having some error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: Error in element 'choose'
> on line 15, column 6: Cannot convert lambda expression to type
> 'IGroup' because it is not a delegate type

Please find below code

```
 <policies>
        <inbound>
        <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Contains(g => g.name == "audit"))">
             <return-response>
                  <set-status code="403" reason="Unauthorized" />
                  <set-body>Users in group audit do not have access to this method. </set-body>
             </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
            <base />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's two different issues with the current policy.

1. The property name is `Name`, not `name` (see [IGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-igroup))
2. You can't use `Contains()`, while `Any()` works

The `context.User.Groups` property is of type `IEnumerable<IGroup>`. [API Management policy expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) only allow/support a selected list of types and members.
The `Contains()` implementation in the supported `System.Linq.Enumerable` class doesn't have an overload accepting a `Func`. It only has `Contains<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)` and `Contains<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)`.

The `Any()` implementation *does* have an overload that accepts a `Func` ([Any(IEnumerable, Func<TSource,Boolean>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-any-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean))))).

So you might need to use `Any()`, checking the `Name` property like this:

`<when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "audit"))">`